# -XX:+PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation in a specific file

Tags: java, jvm

I am looking for a flag to redirect output from `PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation` to a target file.

Does a flag like this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On JDK 8 it's possible to redirect the entire VM output to a file:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log -XX:-DisplayVMOutput
```

On newer JDKs you can use [Unified JVM Logging](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) to redirect only CodeCache related output:

```
-Xlog:compilation+codecache=debug:file=codecache.log
```

Note: `-XX:+PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation` is not needed in the latter case.